# Query working in SQL Server  but dont work in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-server-2005, sqlalchemy

In one program on python i'm making query to SQL Server 2005 via sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (cipher=:value? OR CHARINDEX(cipher_mask,:value?)!=0)
and NOT exists( SELECT * FROM table WHERE CHARINDEX(not_cipher_mask,:value?)!=0 AND code=:code?)
and code=:code?
```

This works fine.

I'm trying to create similar query for SQLite (it does not use function `CHARINDEX`)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where (cipher=:value?  OR :value?  like cipher_mask+'/%')
and not exists (SELECT * FROM table  where code=:code? and :value? like not_cipher_mask +'/%') and code=:code?
```

This works fine in SQL Server 2005, but in SQLite, I get an empty result

Why it is not working here?

P.S. All columns in table are `VARCHAR` with same data

Comment: Are `:c` and `:value` supposed to be different?

Comment: yep, this different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARINDEX(a, b)` is similar to `b LIKE '%' || a || '%'`. (You need the first `%` to find `a` if it is not at the beginning of `b`.)

String concatenation uses `||`, not `+`.

Comment: Thank you, problem is solved. The problem was to use + for concatenation. b LIKE  a || '%' enoth for me